# Generate array with random numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I want to generate in **java** an array with random numbers from 1 to 10 but I need the array to have at least one of each 10 numbers.

**wrong**: `array = {1,2,3,1,3,2,4,5}`

**correct**: `array = {1,2,4,3,6,8,7,9,5,10...}`

The array can have size bigger than 10 but the  0 to 10 numbers must exist in the array.

My code for generating the array so far:

```
public int[] fillarray(int size, int Reel[]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Reel[i] = (int) (Math.random() * symbols);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Reel));

    return Reel;
}
```

Comment: You’ll need to keep track of the numbers as you go along and mark them off once there and only return once all are there.

Comment: You’ll also probably not be able to set the size doing it this way, so arrays are probably not your friend. Perhaps consider a `List` or one of its implementations.  And `Reel` should be `reel`, i.e. lower case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a `List` and [`Collections.shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

And, following @Elliott's helpful advice, you can convert a list to array:

```
int[] result = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Comment: Just like a deck of cards.

Comment: It’s not an `array` as mentioned in the question, but have an upvote for the easy solution.

Comment: I'd add `return list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();` also, you could do `List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(1, 1 + size).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());` which then makes it respect `size` too.

Comment: `List` doesn’t have a fixed size.

Comment: @achAmháin only partially correct. The [documentation of `List.of(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of(E...)) states that it  "*Returns an unmodifiable list containing an arbitrary number of elements.*"

Comment: @Turing85 I was waiting for someone to correct me on a technicality :)